# Guardar valor de un RadioButton seleccionado con sql

Tags: c#, sql

Tengo dos RadioButton, uno contiene el valor "F" y el otro el valor "M"

Necesito saber cual esta seleccionado para insertarlo en la Base de Dato

```
if (sexo == "M")
        {
            rbtn_m.IsChecked = true;
            sexo1 = "M";
        }
        else
        {
            rbtn_f.IsChecked = true;
            sexo1 = "F";
        }
```

lo hago de esta forma pero no funciona

Answer (score 0):

Deberías usasr la propiedad Checked. De la siguiente manera

```
if (sexo == "M")
    {
        rbtn_m.Checked = true;
        sexo1 = "M";
    }
    else
    {
        rbtn_f.Checked = true;
        sexo1 = "F";
    }
```